# how detect ( 2 or 3 ) number lines in opencv

Tags: opencv

How many way to tell if a photo (in a few lines) in opencv

In the example below that line there are 3

http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/images/1511642.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more?

Comment: You tell me where you and I should have done more work on the Hough parameters and a problem is the angle between the lines I want to do in order to recognize and run the command It is likely that some way or multi-line forms is to say: L-shaped right - left L As steep Or bending is significant It is a good algorithm, and if the source was available at this time uploadimage.co.uk/images/6438032.jpg thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dilating the white portion of the image first. This will make the black strip thinner. Once it is thin comparatively, you could use hough lines transform which returns an array of lines it finds. The task would then be as simple as counting the number of elements in the arrray. Of course, you will have to do a lot of trial and error in passing appropriate parameters to the Hough transform, lest it returns you closely spaced lines which represent the same region in your image. You might probably need to group the lines based on the slope and the intercept also.

Comment: You tell me where you and I should have done more work on the Hough parameters and a problem is the angle between the lines I want to do in order to recognize and run the command

It is likely that some way or multi-line forms is to say:
L-shaped right - left L
As steep
Or bending is significant

It is a good algorithm, and if the source was available at this time

http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/images/6438032.jpg

thanks.

Comment: Use the line equation of the lines. With the slope calculate the angles between the lines, if that is what you want.

Comment: hi , how slope calculate the angles between the lines and how do the left and right  ,  source code ? thanks.